# Nginx rewrite makes me crazy

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, request-uri

the URL is:
http://xxxxxx/index.php?route=product/category&path=565

and why the heck the rules below dont work?!?!

THIS - dont work at all:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "^(.*)product/category&path=565"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=174&filter=sale? last;
}
```

THIS - aint work too! =(

```
if ($args ~* "^(.*)product/category&path=565"){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?route=product/category&path=174&podbor=m:feniks? last;
}
```

Comment: If is evil. Use directly rewrite.

Comment: PS all arguments are removed from the uri and placed into `$args`

Answer (score 0):

Both of your rewrite rules work correctly (for me). The problem maybe that your application requires external redirection rather than internal redirection in order to see the change.

Consider using the `redirect` modifier rather than the `last` modifier. Of course, this will mean that the client will also see the rewritten URL.

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite) document for more.